# making sure jquery .load content is finished loading

Tags: jquery, load

i'm loading some html content dynamically through jquery .load.  I'm having a hard time making sure ALL of the content is loaded.  The dynamic loading of the text seems to work fine, it's the loading of the html content that I'm having trouble with.

this is the page, if you click on the blue shield, bottom left image you can see it not animating down to the full height http://www.klossal.com/ but if you look here you can see how it's suppose to load and it works cause it's not dynamically loaded http://www.klossal.com/index_backup.html

This is the part of the script that loads the html

```
$('#images').load(id +".html", function() {

console.log('Loaded'); //Testing Purposes Only
IMG=1; // Loaded
animate_section(); // Attempt Animation 


});
```

and this is the script in total:

```
var a1, a2, a3, a4, IMG;

$(".thumb_container_site").click(function() {

a1=0; //Reset the Loading Variables
a2=0;
a3=0;
a4=0;
IMG=0;

var id = $(this).attr('id');

$('#images').load(id +".html", function() {

console.log('Loaded'); //Testing Purposes Only
IMG=1; // Loaded
animate_section(); // Attempt Animation 


});

$("#info_header").load(id +"_header.txt", function() {

console.log('Loaded'); //Testing Purposes Only
a1=1; // Loaded
animate_section(); // Attempt Animation         

});

$("#content_1").load(id +"_1.txt", function() {

console.log('Loaded'); //Testing Purposes Only
a2=1; // Loaded
animate_section(); // Attempt Animation         

});

$("#content_2").load(id +"_2.txt", function() {

console.log('Loaded'); //Testing Purposes Only
a3=1; // Loaded
animate_section(); // Attempt Animation         

});

$("#content_3").load(id +"_3.txt", function() {

console.log('Loaded'); //Testing Purposes Only
a4=1; // Loaded
animate_section(); // Attempt Animation         

});


});
```

any help I can get on this would be great, thank you.

here is the animation function

```
function animate_section() {

if((a1===1) && (a2===1) && (a3===1) && (a4===1) && (IMG===1)){ //Animate if all thre divs are loaded

$("#top_section").animate({
    height: $("#load_container").outerHeight(true) + 30
}, 300);
$("#grid").animate({
    marginTop: $("#load_container").outerHeight(true) + 300,
    paddingBottom: 300
}, 300);   
}                
}
```

there is also a second function for a slightly different loading structure, but I don't think this should break anything.  This function loads the top left thumbnail content, and that loads totally right,

```
$(".thumb_container_img").click(function() {

a1=0; //Reset the Loading Variables
a2=0;
a3=0;
a4=0;
IMG=0;

var id = $(this).attr('id');


$('#images').empty();



$("<img>", { src: 'http://www.klossal.com/' + id + ".png" }).load(function () {    
$(this).prependTo("#images"), IMG=1 });

$("#info_header").load(id +"_header.txt", function() {

console.log('Loaded'); //Testing Purposes Only
a1=1; // Loaded
animate_section(); // Attempt Animation         

});

$("#content_1").load(id +"_1.txt", function() {

console.log('Loaded'); //Testing Purposes Only
a2=1; // Loaded
animate_section(); // Attempt Animation         

});

$("#content_2").load(id +"_2.txt", function() {

console.log('Loaded'); //Testing Purposes Only
a3=1; // Loaded
animate_section(); // Attempt Animation         

});

$("#content_3").load(id +"_3.txt", function() {

console.log('Loaded'); //Testing Purposes Only
a4=1; // Loaded
animate_section(); // Attempt Animation         

});



});
```

Comment: I would like to see your animate_section() function

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like what is happening is that your load callback is being triggered when the text file is loaded, not when the image itself is loaded. Therefore, your call to outerHeight() is getting the incorrect value because the container element has a height equal to the loaded portion of the image at the time. You should investigate putting an

```
$('#load_container img').on('load', function(){
   //callback or emit an event that will listen and then respond with your callback
});
```

Comment: hmmm,  I'm not exactly sure where I'd put that in the structure, can you help me?

Comment: you can't rely on `load` for images. See disclaimer in docs. Doesn't work for IE when images in cache

Comment: well can you explain to me where to put that code snippet into my code anyways?

Comment: and is there an alternative way to load it then?

Comment: Hey - don't want to be mean here - I did try to look through your code and see if I could find a proper place for this architecture. Your code is very chaotic though and is not following any best practices. Things such as separating semantic markup from the dynamic code in the back, are not in place. Working on your code means going back and forth from ID of element to pieces of code. I recommend looking into semantic markup, event delegation and bubbling, and JSON instead of .txt files - getting that down may help you find a smoother solve for your current problem

Comment: An alternative to way to handle image loading when your code depends on image size (and if you actually care about IE) is to 1) use images of all the same size or 2) use AJAX loading of a JSON file that contains the src/URL of the image, the width, and height, and then build your page and function off of that data

Comment: there are lots of posts on SO about `jquey preload images`. Also in google search

Comment: definitely not mean, honestly is important when trying to help somebody out :)  I really appreciate you giving it a look and the advice, thanks!